# When a documentation topic is approved, and it has multiple examples, the latest activity is flooded by them

Tags: bug, documentation

[image: Documentation overflow]

All of these lines correspond to a single topic that gets approved. I think it'll be better that if a topic is approved, only the last line appears in the activity, probably with how many examples have been submitted.